# VSS bug on Vista?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-vista, visual-sourcesafe

I have a VS2005 solution which uses Visual SourceSafe 6.0 source control.  I am using Vista Ultimate 32 bit.

I keep getting this error when I close a file, and seeming more often when the file is not  actually under source control (e.g. afxwin.h or something like that).  Does not happen 100% of the time though.  Any workarounds?  Hasn't caused any problems yet, but it's annoying.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unexpected error encountered. It is recommended that you restart the 
application as soon as possible.


Error: Unspecified error
File: vsee\lib\path\cvapipath.cpp
Line number: 2459
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best option (if you can) is to move away from VSS6.0.  Its old technology, and especially given that it uses the filesystem, could give you some serious issues under Vista with the new security.

There are a lot of free options available, but if you want to buy something, TFS works quite nicely, although you will also need a SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a real bug in VStudio, you can report it to MS on the product feedback website.. the url is in [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/articles/451329.aspx) which also contains information on how to write a good report.

As an aside, I think you can upgrade to VSS 2005, which is practically identical but has a few updates to it, I think it should work better with VS2005, and IIRC is free with VS2005. If not, upgrade to Subversion :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .suo file